# Html page onLoad calling javascript without submit button

Tags: javascript, forms

i am trying to load a html page with the results of a "get" from another link.The idea is when I open the page, I should see the results of the get displayed.
I tried the following with javascript but with no success. The problem is I always get a submit button on the page. I want the submit to be "pre" done!
Please help. Here is what I have:

```
<body onLoad ="subMe()">
    <script>
       function subMe(){
        document.getElementById("formButton").submit();
       }
    </script>
<div align="center">

<div style="display: hidden;">
    <form action="http://localhost:8000/getusers/" method="get">
        <input type="submit" id="formButton" />
    </form>
</div>
..
</body>
```

Any idea? This is linked to my previous post:[Cgi C program return value to main HTML and display result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810642/cgi-c-program-return-value-to-main-html-and-display-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are submitting a button, not the form.

Try:

```
function subMe() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
}
```

Since you have no need for the submit button, there is also no harm in removing it from the html.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have to submit the form, not the button.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

submit() should be called on the form element, not on a submit button.